# Nagios add "Contact group" name in the email alerts

Tags: nagios

I've been managing a nagios server which was setup by someone else. I found that there's a lot of contact groups configs and contacts_name. I'm trying to disable some of them since some alerts are duplicate.

In order to figure out which groups the email is coming from I'd like to  add contactgroup_name in the email alerts.

I tried to set the variable "$CONTACTGROUP$" in the ./commands/notify.cfg but I don't see any values returned by that in the nagios alerts.

Is there a variable to display CONTACT_GROUP and CONTACT_NAME in nagios email alerts?

```
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nNotification Number : $NOTIFICATIONNUMBER$\nProblem Duration: $SERVICEDURATION$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $SHORTDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n\n $CONTACTGROUP$" | /bin/mail -s "**$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ alert #$NOTIFICATIONNUMBER$ - $HOSTALIAS$:$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$**" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```

Just after the additional info I added the "nAdditional Info:\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n\n $CONTACTGROUP$"" which doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Found some nagios macros in below url. I used $CONTACTGROUPALIAS$ and $CONTACTGROUPMEMBERS$ it worked.

https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/macrolist.html